# What's the typical concentration of medical oxygen?

Tags: oxygen

What's the concentration level of oxygen in a standard medical oxygen gas which is normally found in ambulances or hospitals? Does it contain nitrogen too?

Comment: Posted this as a copy of a deleted question based on: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189223/question-deleted-while-i-was-answering-it since the original question was deleted by the owner while I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Medical oxygen in liquid or compressed cylinders is typically [>99% O<sub>2</sub>](http://ftp.uspbpep.com/v29240/usp29nf24s0_m59550.html), but it is not typically administered at full strength. Instead, patients inspire a mixture of O<sub>2</sub> and room air.

Oxygen concentrator units concentrate to [90-96%](http://ftp.uspbpep.com/v29240/usp29nf24s0_m59560.html), which is called "93% oxygen". The remainder is mostly nitrogen.